# Conditional query string redirect

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

I'm trying to redirect requests that have a query string to a different domain name.

I've got a short url, http://short.url and I want to redirect http://short.url?hello to http://long.url/?hello. So the query string has to be kept by the redirect. To make things more complicated, I would like to rediect http://short.url?hello,hello2 to http://long.url/advanced.aspx/?hello,hello2.

Here is the rule I've got now (only dealing with the first part of my question)

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="test" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="~/?\w+" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://long.url/?{R:0}" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

However, I am not seeing any redirects. Also, is there a better way to do this? Basically I just want to setup a shortcut to pass queries to a website. These are not meant to be permanent so I'm using `redirectType="Found"`.

Comment: FWIW, you could write a HttpHandler and manipulate the URLs directly with C# code to do what you want (or even use the Global.asax directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is looking to do this:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Basic" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="\w*" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://longurl.com" redirectType="Found" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="\w+" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="\," negate="true" />
        </conditions>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Advanced" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="\w*" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://longurl.com/advanced.aspx" redirectType="Found" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^\w+(?=\,)" />
        </conditions>
    </rule>
</rules>
```